# Core Date Entity change issue

Tags: iphone, ios4, core-data, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am working on an iPhone app.
I have modified my data model in Core Data by adding an entity.
And now my app crashes.

I think that when doing that (changing the model) I have to remove some files and reset the data store so that things can work with my new model. But I just can't remember what exactly I need to do.

Thanks for any tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered this one just the other day! It's a common issue. You need to blow away your old database file first. Here's how to do it:

[Adding new attributes in existing coredata model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586498/adding-new-attributes-in-existing-coredata-model/7586983#7586983)

Comment: If you are still in development then @MaxMacLeod is correct.  If you have users with data already then please don't do that.  Do a proper Core Data migration instead.

Comment: yes, very true! Sorry I assumed - perhaps wrongly - that it was a development issue.